# Does pyserial always lower RTS while port is open?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pyserial

I'm using Pyserial to talk to an arduino type setup which cares about RTS. I'm opening the port with the statement below and closing it with port.close()
Monitoring with a logic analyzer I see RTS go low when the port opens and back high when it closes.  It would be better if it stayed high.  I have tried changing the port=serial parameter to rtscts=1 with no change - any suggestions? This is python 2.7 on win10 by the way.

```
port = serial.Serial(port='COM3',parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
       bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
       stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,timeout=5,xonxoff=0,
       rtscts=0,dsrdtr=0,baudrate=9600)
```

Comment: RTS is active low, right? The RTS state on Windows [defaults to enabled](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/serialwin32.py#L33). You can delay opening the port by not passing the port argument. Then set `port.rts = False`, `port.port = 'COM3'`, and call `port.open()`.

Comment: Perfect - Thanks very much!